# Should I capitalise the "N" in "Normal Distribution" in British English?

Tags: normal-distribution, terminology, notation

This question is a bit left-field, but I figured that the community here probably has strong views on the subject!

I am writing up my PhD thesis. Consistently, when talking about quantities which are formally related to a Gaussian distribution, I have capitalised the "N" in "Normal" to refer to them. For example, "[...Under such circumstances] the resulting distribution is not Normal, but rather described by [...]".

My supervisor has read through the relevant chapter, and replaced every single one of these with a lower-case 'n'. I can't find any definitive literature on the subject -- Springer [apparently wanted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44946/why-is-abelian-infrequently-capitalized) names properly capitalised, and according to [another random dude on the internet](http://modelingwithdata.org/pdfs/185-distribution_families.pdf), capitalising distribution names is a Good Idea.

Lacking a definitive style guide for my thesis, I thought I'd turn to the community of experts -- what is commonly done, and why?

Comment: I tend to capitalize "Normal" to emphasize that no member of this family of distributions is "normal."

Comment: Why not just call it a Gaussian distribution and avoid fussing about whether or not to capitaliise the first letter in the word "normal"? If you feel the need to be complete and to cross your eyes and dot your teas, just say at the very first occurrence in your thesis something like, "Throughout this thesis, a random variable with density function ...... shal be referred to as a Gaussian random variable with mean .... and variance .... and the density function shown shall be referred to as a Gaussian density"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For what it's worth, Wikipedia says this on the origin of the name:

> Since its introduction, the normal distribution has been known by many different name... Gauss himself apparently coined the term with reference to the "normal equations" involved in its applications, with normal having its technical meaning of orthogonal rather than "usual". However, by the end of the 19th century some authors had started using the name normal distribution, where the word "normal" was used as an adjective...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Naming

It is also not capitalized in the Wikipedia article, nor have I seen it capitalized in general as an American English speaker. For all intents and purposes normal IS an adjective, though not one that's meant to imply all other distributions are 'abnormal'.

Comment: (+1) this should be the accepted answer. I was mislead by my non-English background. After reviewing multiple sources it seems that in vast majority use lowercase names are used except names based on surnames.

Comment: @Tim that's the standard I've always seen and used

Comment: @ssdecontrol I've seen different usages, check my edited answer. But yes, it seems that lowercase is the standard.

Answer (score 17):

On one hand, "Normal" seems not to be an adjective, nor a feature of some distribution that it is more normal than any other (or more "beta", more "binomial"). "Normal" is a name of a distribution and can to be considered as a [proper noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun#Capitalization), and so be capitalized. As *@Scortchi* noticed in his comment, this is also a general term and people seem to capitalize such terms. If you look into the literature, you'll see that [some](https://books.google.pl/books?id=th3fbFI1DaMC&lpg=PP1&dq=statistical%20inference&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=normal%20distribution&f=false) authors capitalize all the names of distributions, while some seem to never do so.

On another hand, currently (e.g. by [Forbes et al.](https://books.google.pl/books?id=YhF1osrQ4psC&printsec=frontcover&dq=statistical%20distribution&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=normal&f=false), [Krishnamoorty](https://books.google.pl/books?id=FEE8D1tRl30C&printsec=frontcover&dq=statistical%20distribution&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=normal&f=false), [Fisher](https://books.google.pl/books?id=mYe6je7N0aQC&lpg=PP1&dq=statistical%20inference&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=normal%20distribution&f=false), [Cox et al.](https://books.google.pl/books?id=ppoujo-BInsC&lpg=PR1&dq=statistics&pg=PR1#v=onepage&q=normal%20distribution&f=false) and others), it seems that most commonly names of distributions are **written in lowercase** (e.g. normal, beta, binomial) and are capitalized if they come from surnames (e.g. Cauchy, Gaussian, Poisson). There are also some names that are always written in lowercase as $t$-distribution (example [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2342041?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)). While Halperin et al. (1965) in their recommendations do not mention distribution names, in their text they write about chi-squared and standarized normal distributions in lowercase.

This convention may be confusing since in formulas names of distributions are almost always written capitalized (e.g. $X \sim \mathrm{Normal}(\mu, \sigma)$ or $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma)$) and also because many names come from surnames. However, contrary to my initial answer, it seems that lowercase names are used more commonly and so can be considered as a current convention.

[image]

(image source: Freeman, 2006)

---

Halperin, M., Hartley, H.O., and Hoel, P.G. (1965). [Recommended Standards for Statistical Symbols and Notation. COPSS Committee on Symbols and Notation.](http://phdtree.org//pdf/53843883-recommended-standards-for-statistical-symbols-and-notation/) *The American Statistician, 19*(3): 12–14.

Freeman, A. (2006). [A visual comparison of normal and paranormal distributions.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2465539/) *J Epidemiol Community Health, 60*(1): 6.

Comment: I'd say "normal" in this context is an adjective and therefore should not be capitalised. However, "Gaussian" would be capitalised. This seems to be the accepted usage on the Wiki page for the normal distribution.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Normal Distribution" then, if it's a proper name? Seems to me it's rather like the "Mountain Bluebird" example in that Wikipedia article.

Comment: It's a bit deceptive to quote Wikipedia in support of capitalization, when they uniformly lowercase "normal distribution": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

Comment: @Tim: I seem to remember the capitalized version being more common than it is now, & I think your answer correctly identifies the motivation. People used to be more prone to capitalize general terms akin to proper names. So you might wish to edit it to point out current usage, but it'd be a shame to delete it.

Comment: I down-voted not because the answer is bluntly wrong but to steer people towards Grace's answer. (Otherwise your answer is quite nice!)

Comment: Thanks for the paranormal distribution reference – this will make a nice easter egg in my thesis.

Comment: @Scortchi: That's because bird names are capitalized (http://penelopedia.blogspot.ca/2010/12/bird-names-to-capitalize-or-not.html)  In general, I don't think English capitalizes the names of animals ("the white tiger" or plants ("the white oak") or things ("the white dwarf").

Comment: @David "Just wrong" seems to be going too far. No part of the meaning of "proper noun" concerns the singularity or plurality of the referent. Plenty of proper nouns refer to families, such as the Obamas, the Beatles, or a Gaussian (which is even a synonym for "normal distribution"!).

Comment: @NeilG The International Ornithologist's Union has decided that bird names will be capitalized in its own publications. It has no authority whatsoever to demand that anyone else to deviate from normal English orthography in this way.

Comment: @whuber I've deleted my comment, since it referred to an earlier version of the answer. But I note that the author's revision comment also describes that version as "wrong".

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Sure, but wikipedia decided to follow their convention.

Comment: @NeilG: I'm sure there are still naturalists around who write "The Brown Rat is ubiquituous [...]", or "Despite its fearsome reputation, the Adder [...]", or of the "White Oak" (not "White Tiger" though - that's not a species). I don't recall if I've seen "White Dwarf" or not, but if I did see it I'd take it as the writer's signalling that the term denotes rather than connotes; refers to *these* stars regardless of whether better telescopes might reveal them to be emerald green, & gigantic; perhaps designates a natural kind like biological species or chemical elements.

Comment: @Scortchi: There may be, but that's not prescriptive english as prescribed by any dictionary (e.g. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/white%20dwarf?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic)  German works the way you describe though.

Comment: Guys, this discussion is pretty interesting, maybe we should start a thread at http://english.stackexchange.com/ ..?